# text view shape is shown as oval even though the shape is cirlce

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I created a circular shape called circle.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid
        android:color="#FFF" />
    <size
        android:width="5dp"
        android:height="5dp"/>

    <padding
        android:left="5dip"
        android:right="5dip"
        android:top="5dip"
        android:bottom="5dip" />
</shape>
```

In the preview it looks circular and not oval. Then I implemented it in my text view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addToCartBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/cart_button_text"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="65dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cartItemsCountTV"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/addToCartBtn"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then the result is still an oval shape:

[image]

The shape only becomes circular when the text is two digits such as "10". Why is it oval even though it should be circular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same `layout_width` and `layout_height` to keep it as circle instead of `wrap_content`.

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    ..../>
```

> Using a View's size to `wrap_content` will force it to expand only far
>   enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains.